# Cannot pass ObservableCollection<Video> from one page to another

Tags: parameters, maui, observablecollection

I can't pass an `ObservableCollection<Video>` from one page to another.  I use this same pattern all over my project, so I'm not sure why it's failing here.  I'm using the MVVM pattern.

Here's my code:

### On the "throw" side

I declare the `ObservableCollection<Video>` and instantiate it in the constructor:

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<Video> videoList;

//...

public Constructor()
{   
    VideoList = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
}
```

The method that sets up the pass:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
private async Task CreateCase()
{
    if (0 == VideoList.Count)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No video(s) selected", "You must have at least one video selected to add to your new Case.", "", "OK");
        return;
    }

    Dictionary<string, object> param = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "VideoList", VideoList }
    };

    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(CreateCasePage)}", param);
}
```

The `ObservableCollection<Video>` makes it into this method and into the Dictionary.  Here's a screenshot just to confirm.  In the code, I chose three objects, and lo and behold they are in the list:
[image]

### On the "Catch" side

The `ObservableCollection<Video>` is declared, and the `QueryProperty` is used.  The same name is used on both the 'throw' page and 'catch' page:

```cs
[QueryProperty("VideoList", "VideoList")]
public partial class CreateCasePageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region Properties
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Video> videoList;

    //...

    public Constructor()
    {
        VideoList = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I should 'new' the `ObservableCollection<Video>` on the 'catch' side, but I've tried newing and and *not* newing it and have the same results.

### Results

The `ObservableCollection<Video>` is always null on the 'catch' side, regardless of what I try. The thing is, I use this same code elsewhere in my project and it works.

I'm not sure what else to look at to debug.

### EDIT: Using ApplyQueryAttributes but not working

I was advised to use the `ApplyQueryAttributes` interface, and this has gotten me closer, but it's not quite working.

My "throw" side code is the same, that is, I simply pass the `ObservableObject<object>` to the "catch" side with a dictionary:

```
    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task CreateCase()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> param = new()
        {
            { "VideoList", VideoList }
        };

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(CreateCasePage)}", param);
    }
```

On the 'catch' side, I add the `IQueryAttributable` interface:

```
public partial class CreateCasePageViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Video> videoList;

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        VideoList = query["VideoList"] as ObservableCollection<Video>;
    }
}
```

This *almost* works.  When I put a breakpoint inside the interface, `VideoList` is populated, and looks good.
[image]

However, when I attempt to access `VideoList` elsewhere in the ViewModel, I get an exception:

[image]

This is confounding.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the *string-based query parameters* and *object-based navigation data* approaches here. You can check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-a-single-method) for more information.

Your receiving ViewModel should implement the *IQueryAttributable* interface instead of using a *QueryProperty*:

```cs
public partial class CreateCasePageViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Video> videoList;

    public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        VideoList = query["VideoList"] as ObservableCollection<Video>;
    }
}
```

This is necessary, because only simple types and strings can be passed as *string-based query parameters*.

Comment: I don't think that's correct (but I could be wrong).  When the IDictionary object is created, it's `<string, object>`.  At least, that's my interpretation of the docs and the fact that I use this exact same code all the time to pass all kinds of different objects.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Obviously my "Ackshually I use this code everywhere" statement is wrong (although I really do, but I've never used it to pass an `ObservableCollection`, just single objects).

Comment: Well, the simple approach with the *string-based query parameters* may also work for objects that only consist of simple types, but collections are not among them, AFAIK.

Comment: Let me ask you this:  when I try to use the ObservableObject list, I'm getting an exception:  `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'VideoList' was not present in the Dictionary.`   The "VideoList" is populated in the interface implementation, but I get that when I try to access it elsewhere in the ViewModel.  Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: Also, I take that back about not passing `ObsevableCollection<object>` normally -- I do it twice in this project elsewhere.  So... I'm back to square one.

Comment: Maybe share more of your code, especially the code that throws that exception you're mentioning.